# IIS6 to IIS7 - The root element must match the name of the section referencing the file, 'appSettings'

Tags: iis-7.5

I am moving all my localhost applications from a WinXP/IIS6 machine to a Win7/IIS7.5 one. I copied a few folders from the wwwroot directory of WinXP to wwwroot of Win7. Then created a virtual directory and converted to an application. When I browse this application, I get the error:

```
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The root element must match the name of the section referencing the file, 'appSettings'

Source Error:

Line 1:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
Line 2:  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
Line 3:  <head>
Line 4:  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />


Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm    Line: 2
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default app pool for this application was .Net 4.0. Changed it to another apppool of v2.0 and the error went away.